# Printing Mathcad files

Tags: printing, cygwin

I am trying to automate printing of *Mathcad* Sheets using **cygwin** or ubuntu.

`lpr` command does its job when it comes to text file but when I want to use it for mathcad, it gives me following error:

```
 lpr myfile.xmcd
lpr: can't open 'myfile.xmcd' for input
```

I was wondering if there's a way to open the file in its default application and print it from there.

It can be done by `SendKeys` through a vbscript, but not the best option as it needs to figure out a way to wait for the file to be loaded or printing to be done.

Just couple of notes that I ran into while using <kbd>Command Window</kbd>:

**Note**: Mathcad sheets have XML format and `Out-Print` command gives a PDF of the XML.

**Note-2:** `cmd.exe /C ASSOC .xmcd` gives me `.xmcd=Mathcad`.

And, `cmd.exe /c ftype Mathcad` gives me `Mathcad="C:\Program Files (x86)\Mathcad\Mathcad 15\mathcad.exe" /dde`.

Comment: `cygstart myfile.xmcd` shoud run Mathcad and open the file

Comment: @matzeri Yes, equivalent of `START` in cmd. But I want to automate printing.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1207549/automate-printing-mathcad-sheets-to-pdf/1207623#1207623

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but the manual of `cygstart` reports:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    cygstart  [-oxefp?]  [-a  action]  [-d directory] [--hide] [--maximize]
>    [--minimize] [--restore] [--show]  [--showmaximized]  [--showminimized]
>    [--showminnoactive]    [--showna]   [--shownoactivate]   [--shownormal]
>    [--usage] [--version] [--license] [--reference] file [arguments]
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    cygstart is a command-line tool which allows you to let Windows start a
>    program  or  open  a  file or URL in its associated application.  It is
>    similar to the Windows command-line start command.
> ```
>
> OPTIONS
>          Action options
>
> ....
>
> ```
>    -p, --print
>           Short for: --action print
> ```

so

```
cygstart --print myfile.xmcd
```

should produce the desired effect.